# SQL SELECT Сумма строк

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Вывести список проектов с указанием сумм, выплачиваемых их участникам (зарплаты и надбавки).

```
    SELECT PROJECT.Project, SUM(Salary), SUM(Bonus)
    FROM PROJECT
    INNER JOIN PROJECT_EMP ON PROJECT_EMP.ID_Project=PROJECT.ID_Project
    INNER JOIN EMP ON PROJECT_EMP.ID_Emp=EMP.ID_Emp
    LEFT JOIN BONUS ON BONUS.ID_Emp=EMP.ID_Emp
    GROUP BY PROJECT.Project
```

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Но нужно, чтобы вместо двух последних столбиков был один с их суммой

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT PROJECT.Project, SUM(Salary) + ISNULL( SUM(Bonus), 0)
FROM PROJECT
INNER JOIN PROJECT_EMP ON PROJECT_EMP.ID_Project=PROJECT.ID_Project
INNER JOIN EMP ON PROJECT_EMP.ID_Emp=EMP.ID_Emp
LEFT JOIN BONUS ON BONUS.ID_Emp=EMP.ID_Emp
GROUP BY PROJECT.Project
```

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 1):

используйте SUM(Salary) + SUM(Bonus)

Comment: не подходит. последняя строчка получается НУЛЛ. НУЛЛ + число = НУЛЛ

Answer (score 1):

Осталось только добавить '**+**' и название поля **Sum** для наглядности

```
SELECT PROJECT.Project, SUM(Salary) **+** SUM(Bonus) **AS Sum**
    FROM PROJECT
    INNER JOIN PROJECT_EMP ON PROJECT_EMP.ID_Project=PROJECT.ID_Project
    INNER JOIN EMP ON PROJECT_EMP.ID_Emp=EMP.ID_Emp
    LEFT JOIN BONUS ON BONUS.ID_Emp=EMP.ID_Emp
    GROUP BY PROJECT.Project
```

Comment: не подходит. последняя строчка получается НУЛЛ. НУЛЛ + число = НУЛЛ

Comment: В следующий раз уточняйте какую БД используете, в тегах есть и MySQL и MSSql,  это далеко не одно и тоже

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SUM(salary) + IFNULL(SUM(bonus), 0)
```

Если сумма `SUM(salary)` тоже может приобретать значение `NULL`, то и её аналогично обернуть в вызов `IFNULL()`. Это в MySQL, в MS SQL же аналогом этой функции является `ISNULL()`.

Comment: пробовал так - ошибку пишет. не нравится ему что агрегатная функция внутри ifnull

Comment: вместо IFNULL нужно использовать ISNULL. MS SQL почему-то не работает корректно с ним

Comment: @neko69, я на MySQL только проверял. Посмотрел сейчас, действительно в MS SQL эта функция называется ISNULL. Дополню ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В MS SQL надо SUM(ISNULL(Salary, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Bonus, 0)).
 Вообще, если поле может содержать NULL, то в агрегатных функциях нужно внутри функции проврять на NULL.
 Если прменять как ISNULL(SUM(Bonus), 0), то можно получить неверный результат в следующем случае: если только в некоторых строках группируемых данных в поле Bonus есть NULL, а у остальных реальное значение, то эти значения не будут учитываться
 (к примеру по проекту А:
 * Сотрудник1 - Бонус=10
 * Сотрудник2 - Бонус=5
* Сотрудник3 - Бонус=NULL.
 При ISNULL(SUM(Bonus), 0) результат будет 0, 
При SUM(ISNULL(Bonus, 0)) результат будет 15)